# how to set a NX custom command with configuration vars?

Tags: monorepo

So inside my NX workspace, I got multiple projects that need to be deployed differently.

What I would like to have is a deployment script that sorts out the development and production enviroments.

So I would like to be able to run `nx run-many -target=deploy --configuration=production`

And then have something like this:

```json
"deploy": {
  "executor": "nx:run-commands",
  "configuration": {
    "production": {"deploymentBucket": "s3://prod-bucket"},
    "development": {"deploymentBucket": "s3://dev-bucket"}
  },
  "options": {
    "command": "echo b {deploymentBucket} f"
  }
}
```

So that I can run it in my ci pipeline.

Comment: So incase someone finds this, i think the best way is to simply create an nx executor. its honestly a really great developer experience, really recommend it